# How to synchronize frames

Tags: frames, synchronization

2 frames are sharing global variables

the second frame display depends on the variables set by the the php script of first frame

Most of time it works .. but if the second frame is faster it's mess up

how can i synchronize them ?

the second php script of one frame will wait till the other finishes

actually sleep(1) in the beginning improved things a lot but it's not very reliable since the first frame accesses db and the result depends on execution time

Answer (score 0):

finally i have done it using javascript. The first script generates

top.frames[1].location = ....

with parameter exec=1

initially the frame is called with different parameter exec=0

if ($_GET['exec'] == '0') return; // in the beginning of second php